# Dockerで作成したSQLのWordPressDBが自動的に削除されてしまう

Tags: mysql, docker, wordpress, database, docker-compose

## 試したこと

初期にはmysqlのマウントができていないのかと思い色々試行錯誤しましたが、
マウントして一時的には正常にローカル(CentOS)にマウントされているにもかかわらず、
翌日くらいにはやはり接続エラーでWordPressがDBへの接続エラーとなってしまいます。

wp-configも確認しましたが、設定というかそもそもDB自体が存在しなくなってしまうため、
根本的な原因は別の箇所にあるようです。

なお、別のDocker-composeでNginxとLet's Encryptなどは実装しています。
ただ今回は関係なさそうですので割愛しています。(必要であれば貼らせていただきます。)

## 該当のソースコード

```
version: '2'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    container_name: wp_1
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - /home/web2/wordpress/wp_1/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    external_links:
      - mysql
    expose:
      - 80
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: [ドメイン名]
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: [パスワード]
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: [ドメイン名]
     LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: [メールアドレス]
    restart: always
    networks:
      - net-proxy

  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7.21
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    expose: 
      - "3306"
    volumes:
      - /home/web2/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    volumes_from: 
      - storage
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=[パスワード]
    networks:
      - net-proxy

  storage:
    container_name: storage
    build: /home/web2/storage
    volumes:
      - /home/web2/storage/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - net-proxy

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=mysql
      - PMA_USER=root
      - PMA_PASSWORD=[パスワード]
    links:
      - mysql
    ports:
       - 8080:80
    volumes:
       - /sessions
    networks:
      - net-proxy

networks:
  net-proxy:
    external: true
```

Comment: SQLでログを残すように設定して、何が原因でSQLが停止した(接続でいなくなった)、あるいはWordPressが使っているテーブルが削除されたのかを確認しては如何ですか？　何が起きたのかが判れば、それに至る原因を絞り込めるかと思います。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/192674